# Cannot use authentication header in 'php-jira-rest-client'

Tags: php, curl, jira, postman, jira-rest-api

I want to use the Jira REST API to generate jira issues. I found the [php-jira-rest-client](https://github.com/lesstif/php-jira-rest-client) library, but I have problems with the authentication. I was able to succesfully create Jira issues with postman, by setting the [authentication header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) and posting the respective json file to the jira server. The `authentication header` was base64 encoded (user:password). I was also able to successfully post and get REST requests to the Jira API by using curl:

```
$ch = curl_init( 'https://jira.somedomain.com/rest/api/2/issue/' ); 
$ticket_json = file_get_contents("/path_to/jira_ticket.json");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ticket_json );
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic ---SOME-CREDENTIALS---',
);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But when I use the same credentials with the `php-jira-rest-client`, I'm getting an bad request 400 error. I have no idea why this behavior is different.